# Yii and array_pop in view arrived as second parameter

Tags: php, yii, controller, render

I'm trying to pass array data from the controller to the view but the view lost the "Yii format" (header bootstrap),the header doesn't appear and only show a "plane text".

This is happening when I try to extract the elements with `array_pop`.

*View: magazines.php*

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name;
?>
<h3>
    <?php    
        $aux_string = "";   
        foreach ( $files_format as $aux_string ) {
            $aux_string->array_pop($files_format);
        }
    ?>
</h3>
```

*Controller: SiteController.php*

```
public function actionMagazines()
{
            $path="pdfs/";
            $directory=dir($path);
            $files=array();
            while (false !== ($entry = $directory->read()))
            {   
                 if($entry!="."&&$entry!=".."){
                    array_push($files, $entry);
                    print_r($files);
                 }
            }

            $this->render('magazines', array('files_format'=> $files));
}
```

In another way, if I don't use array_pop the "Yii format" remains intact (Below, the code line with `array_pop` that is commented with which the view is showed correctly)

```
           ...
           //$aux_string->array_pop($files_format);
           ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want to do is:

```
    $aux_string = "";   
    foreach ( $files_format as $string ) {
        $aux_string.=$string ;
    }
```

or:

```
    $aux_string = join('',$files_format);
```

Comment: Not exactly; nevertheless, you has done that I understand it the mistake that I was making with the foreach construct. Cheers Claude!

Comment: The mistake was that I didn't understand the foreach clause. I thought that it was needed to extract also the values in loop (into the square brackets). On the other hand, for that is the foreach (Iterator).

Answer (score 0):

Really, the mistake is resolved by changing one code line in `foreach` loop.

For that, I understand that the trouble with "*view*" be due to treat manually the stack; while `foreach` is doing it internally to automatic mode.

*View: magazines.php*

```
<?php
/* @var $this SiteController */

$this->pageTitle=Yii::app()->name;
?>
<h3>
    <?php    
        $aux_string = "";   
        foreach ( $files_format as $aux_string ) {
            echo $aux_string."<br><br>";
        }
    ?>
</h3>
```